# Strange off-by-one error in COUNT(DISTINCT) vs SELECT DISTINCT

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is structured like this:

```
WITH 
  cte1 AS (
    ...
  ),
  cte2 AS (
    ...
  )

  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cte2.id)
  FROM  cte1 LEFT JOIN cte2 ON 
       ...
)
```

which returns

```
792402
```

However, when I replace

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cte2.id)
```

with

```
SELECT DISTINCT cte2.id
```

the "message" in MySQLWorkbench says

```
792403 rows returned
```

Due to the size of the dataset I am finding it incredibly difficult to create a mininum working example of this that I can post.

What could be going on here ?

Comment: Does this happen on a small data set,

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, it doesn't, at least I haven;t been able to recreate it yet. I am in the process of incrementally adding data until it occurs, but as you can imagine, this is a painfully slow prcedure.

Comment: Could it be that a new row is being added between the 2 queries

Comment: @RiggsFolly No, definitely not. I have re-run it so many times now !!